# mysql disable referential integrity

Tags: mysql, constraints, referential-integrity

I want to drop all the schemas in a mysql db, and I don't want to be bothered with referential integrity errors

in h2 it's done like this

```
SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;
drop table if exists company;
drop table if exists computer;
SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY TRUE;
```

How can it be achieved in mysql?

Comment: thanks a lot, both solutions worked, I just selected the first one as correct, and upvoted both...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
SET @@foreign_key_checks = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS computer;

SET @@foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 14):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS computer;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```